# "Unable to find service record" when transfering files from 1 laptop to another after setting up a connection

Tags: bluetooth, file-sharing

I have paired 2 laptops using `Set up new device` but can't send files from one to another. it shows `unable to find service record` . I am using ubuntu 12.04 now. Kindly help me! But i can send files from both laptop to phones.

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into this just now punting a file from my Linux machine to my Macbook.  The message "***Unable to find Service Record***" is a red-herring.  It leads you to believe the ***SENDING*** device is not configured correctly, when in fact the permissions are not set correctly on the ***REMOTE*** device.

Once I set ticked "***Bluetooth Sharing***" in my Macbook's "***Sharing***" settings, I was able to send files from my Linux host to it:

[image: OSX Settings Dialogue for Bluetooth]

Obviously these settings will live in different places depending on the OS of the file target.

Comment: Thank you. The Bluetooth Sharing was already turned on, so I had to turn it *off* and then *on* back. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command `bluetooth-sendto --device=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX file1 file2..` where XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is the address of other laptop, which you can find from **Bluetooth Settings** dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by using " personal file Sharing". I have enabled share file over bluetooth & Receive files in download folder over bluetooth.

Comment: Ok, then accept your own answer as the correct one.

Comment: Where is this option (Personal File Sharing)?